# Could not find file at given path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on my school project and I'm trying to insert data and upload an image file to the database but I got this error.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Here is the code:
I cannot understand what does error means.

```
public static void AddItems(StoreItems i)
{

    byte[] bytes;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.PicturePath))
    {
        string filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/default-artwork.png");
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    }

    else
    {
        string filename = i.PicturePath;
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);


    }


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DAL.cs);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO AlbumsTb ( AlbumName, Artist, Genre, DateReleased, Price, Downloads, Listens, RecordLabel, DateAdded, AlbumArt) VALUES( @AlbumName, @Artist, @Genre, @DateReleased, @Price, @Downloads, @Listens, @RecordLabel, @DateAdded, @AlbumArt)", con);
    //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", i.ID);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.AlbumName;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.Artist;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.Genre;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateReleased", SqlDbType.Date).Value = i.DateReleased;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",i.Price);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Downloads", i.Downloads);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Listens", i.Listens);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordLabel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.RecordLabel;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"DateAdded", DateTime.Now.ToString());

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumArt", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Based on the code in your previous question you have not saved the file anywhere in the calling method. So even though the object has a picture path, nothing was saved with that name.

Comment: Furthermore, he shouldn't be saving anything in the very IIS folder.

Comment: You should also stop posting images and instead properly format the question with the actual error message so that it be easier to process the details.

Comment: The error means that the file you specified doesn't exist in the location you specified in the `filename` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code in your previous question you have not saved the file anywhere in the calling method. So even though the object has a picture path, nothing was saved with that name. Therefore there is nothing to read.

The error message states that it cannot find a file at the provided path. Which is true since you did not save anything at that location.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItems(FormCollection form)
{
    //...other code removed for brevity

    byte[] bytes;
    var files = Request.Files;
    if(files.Count > 0) {
        var stream = files[0].InputStream;
        //Get image data from stream and stored in bytes
        using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    } else {
        //...Set default image data.
        var filename = this.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/default-artwork.png");
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    }

    //Assuming a property to hold the image data byte[] AlbumArt { get; set; }
    i.AlbumArt = bytes;

    DAL.AddItems(i);
    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Refactor DAL to take the bytes as input parameter or have it as a byte[] property on the input class.

```
public static void AddItems(StoreItems i) { 
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(DAL.cs) {
        con.Open();
        var sql = "INSERT INTO AlbumsTb ( AlbumName, Artist, Genre, DateReleased, Price, Downloads, Listens, RecordLabel, DateAdded, AlbumArt) VALUES( @AlbumName, @Artist, @Genre, @DateReleased, @Price, @Downloads, @Listens, @RecordLabel, @DateAdded, @AlbumArt)";
        using(var com = new SqlCommand(sql, con) {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.AlbumName;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.Artist;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.Genre;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateReleased", SqlDbType.Date).Value = i.DateReleased;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",i.Price);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Downloads", i.Downloads);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Listens", i.Listens);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordLabel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.RecordLabel;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumArt", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = i.AlbumArt;

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input parameter is pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\" location as you are executing your application on IIS Express. The path are storing in StoreItems.PicturePath is wrong.

Debug the code in which you are setting this path.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you are trying to access that file in the wrong folder, the message leaves no doubts. I would do something like this:

```
string filename = i.PicturePath;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
{
    filename = "default-artwork.png";
}
string fullPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + filename);
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
```